# Java not finding the information

Tags: java, xml, converters

I can not get the data to correctly be inserted. Ever one that says NULL should have information in them, ID = 56512, Fist Name = Thomas and so on. This also is a converter, so for the future it most be able to change the information, as long it is sample 1 text

A few thinks i have change the input information

```
public static void outputXML(String filename, String sampletxt, String dataxml)
    {
        try {
            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
                pw.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
                pw.println("<!-- XML Converter byWe-Code-Stuff, LLC.Developer: Benjamin Bolyard -->");
                pw.println("<accounts>");
                pw.println("<account>");
                String Id = null;
                pw.println("<manager employeeId>" + Id);
                String data = null;
                String firstName = null;
                pw.println("<first>" + firstName + "</first>");
                String lastName = null;
                pw.println("<last>" + lastName + "</last>");
                pw.println("</manager>");
                pw.println("<location>");
                String city = null;
                pw.println("<city>" + city + "<city>");
                String state = null;
                pw.println("<state>" + state + "</state>");
                String zip = null;
                pw.println("<zipcode>" + zip + "</zipcode>");
                String count = null;
                pw.println("<companies count>" + count);
                String companyname = null;
                pw.println("<companies>" + companyname + "</companies>");
                pw.println("</companies>");
                pw.println("</location>");
                pw.println("</account>");
                pw.println("</accounts>");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }

sample

56512: THOMAS KACI BRADFORD TN 37059
56512: ENCOMPASS SERVICES CORPORATION
56512: BURLINGTON COAT FACTORY WAREHOUSE CORPORATION
56512: WEATHERFORD INTERNATIONAL, INC
56512: CYTEC INDUSTRIES, INC
56512: --END_MANAGER--
10777: ROBINSON BRIONNA HUNTLAND TN 37889
10777: UNITED PARCEL SERVICE, INC
10777: GENERAL CABLE CORPORATION
10777: GENTEK, INC
10777: QUESTAR CORP.
10777: AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES
10777: CHARTER ONE FINANCIAL, INC
10777: KINDRED HEALTHCARE, INC
10777: --END_MANAGER--
```

Correct information replacing NULL.

Comment: JavaScript !== Java

Comment: Make a class that has those values as a field, those fields get defined when you create the object from some source, then use the class fields directly in this part of the code.

Comment: `String Id = null; pw.println("<manager employeeId>" + Id);` how do you expect *anything* but `null` in the output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Do not generate XML code by hand, you will make mistakes when you do. Use a proper library to create XML documents.